# Safest way to send JSON string to PHP server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to send a JSON string to PHP server like this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "themes.php?page=themeoptions",  
    data: {structure : JSON.stringify(structure)},    
});
```

However, every quotation mark from the string I send is escaped automatically, so I can't decode it in PHP with json_decode(). I could remove all the escape characters, but I really doubt that this way of sending JSON data to server is safe.

So, I was wondering if you have any ideas on how to do that in a **simple** and safe (not necessarily bulletfroof) way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `'{"structure":' +  JSON.stringify(structure) + '}'` or `{structure: structure}`

The first one is a JSON String so jQuery doesn't need to parse it. The second is a javascript object, so jQuery knows exactly how to parse it.

But you are mixing the two, so jQuery is confused and re-encodes your object, because you encoded only half your object.

So another alternative would be `JSON.stringify({structure: structure })`

Comment: jQuery isn't "confused", it does simply what it's supposed to do: JSON encoding an object that contains a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "themes.php?page=themeoptions",  
    data: {structure: structure},    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "themes.php?page=themeoptions",  
    data: structure,    
});
```

Quoting from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

> **dataObject** *String*
>  
>  Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).